# how to retrieve Abandoned cart Item details in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am writing an REST API in Magento to retrieve the Abandoned cart Item details. I can able to retrieve Abandoned cart details ( like user email, name and date.) In that I would like to get the product details ?
Please find the below code , currently I am using it. from this How can I retrieve product details also ?

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/quote_collection');
$collection->prepareForAbandonedReport(); 
$output = $collection->load()->toArray();
```

The above code working fine with abandoned cart user details.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be easy to get details. But I haven't found how to get options

```
$quotes = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/quote_collection');
    foreach ($quotes as $quote) {
        $cart_items = $quote->getItemsCollection()->getItems();
        foreach ($cart_items as $item) {
            print_r($item->getData());
        }
    }
```